# How can i remove the side lines when selecting a text in IOS in react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native, textinput, react-native-textinput, selectedtext

[image]

As you can see in the above image I want to remove both the sidelines in ios in react- native, I have tried every prop available in the text-input but nothing is working.
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think thats possible even on native side